# sumproduct Formula array in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

```
ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT((""" & Source1_Val & """ = " & Target1 & ")*(""" & Source2_Val & """ = " & target2 & ")*ROW(" & Target1 & "))")
```

The same formula works when I directly put in Excel but when done throught VBA I am not getting any result.

Excel formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Source!Q2=Q1:Q33)*(Source!L2 = L1:L33)*ROW(L1:L33))
```

Comment: But you aren't assigning your `.Evaluate` to anything or doing anything with it.  What are you expecting to happen with that VBA statement?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [MSDN -Using Ranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa139976%28v=office.10%29.aspx)?

```
Range("AD:AD").Select
Range("AE:AE").Select
```

Comment: no actually when i use the range in that sumproduct formula we get a error. I did define a name range and used it, but this works when i use it in formula bar and not in VBA. So i am looking for something where i cab replace AD:AD and AE:AE

Answer (score 0):

Are Column1, etc., all defined names? Then:

```
.Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT((Column1=Source1_Val)*(Column2=Source2_Val)*ROW())")
```

Comment: column1 and column2 holds the defined name (name1 and name2 are its defined names - column headers) i want to change this for every run so using a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty dumb. Remove the `=` sign from the text.

Assume that the cell `D7:D9` as well as `E7:E9` contains numeric values, the following function works well in the immediate window

```
?Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(D7:D9, E7:E9)")
```

EDIT: With the assumption that all the variables names below are string.

```
dim myFormula as string
myFormula =  "SUMPRODUCT((" & Source1_Val & " = " & Target1 & ")" _
& " * (" & Source2_Val _
& " = " & target2 & ")*ROW(" & Target1 & "))"

ActiveSheet.Evaluate(myFormula)
```

There is no need to include extra double-quotes in the formula.

EDIT2: Based on the attached file, here is the code to show that it works

```
option explicit
Sub TestFormulaStringUsingEvaluate()
Dim formula As String

Dim source1_Val As String
Dim source2_Val As String
Dim target1 As String
Dim target2 As String

'** Fill in the values for the following 4 variables
source1_Val = "Source!Q2"
target1 = "Target!Q$1:Q$10"

source2_Val = "Source!L2"
target2 = "Target!L$1:L$10"


formula = "SUMPRODUCT((" & source1_Val & "= " & target1 & ") " _
& "*(" & source2_Val & "=" & target2 & ") " _
& "* ROW(" & target2 & "))"

MsgBox Application.Evaluate(formula)
End Sub
```

Comment: @Srivardhan: Try putting the formula text in a string variable, as described above. If it throws the error, print the formula using `msgbox(myFormula)` - the text of which you can compare against what you typed in the formula bar.

Comment: I AM GETTING A 2015 ERROR WHEN I TRY TO ASSIGN THAT ROW NUMBER TO A VARIABLE. THE MSGBOX GIVES THE CORRECT FORMULA THOUGH

Comment: @Srivardhan: Are all your variables `Source_Val1`, `Target`, `Source2_Val`, `Target2` strings? What value does each of the variable contain? Please post it here. What does `Row(L1:L33)` return? How is that useful?

Comment: this is a two column look up, when i solve each of (" & Source1_Val & " = " & Target1 & ") and (" & Source2_Val & " = " & Target2 & ") i get true of false which intrun get me the matching row. The values have strings like "ABC1234"

Comment: If you can, share the workbook OR give example of cell data (that is present) and the output you are looking for. I guess `SUMPRODUCT` is not what you need.

Comment: please find the file here - https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=FEACF1BEF126B3A2&resid=FEACF1BEF126B3A2!110&authkey=AAk4h3ijeIAX_BY&em=2%22%20width=%22402%22%20height=%22346%22%20frameborder=%220%22%20scrolling=%22no%22